# What is actual SQL produced by cursor.execute() through python dbapi 2.0?

Tags: python, python-db-api

I'll admit it. I've been doing this for literally decades:

```
sql = 'select * from whatever where key = "%s"' % ('thing')
cursor.execute(sql)
```

One big reason is that

```
print(sql)
```

tells me something useful. Whereas this:

```
sql = 'select * from whatever where key = :key'
params = {'key': 'thing'}
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

has no way to do that. Or does it? Note that this isn't as easy as doing this:

```
print(replace_with_dict_values(sql, params))
```

(replace_with_dict_values isn't real, but could easily be made.)  Why not? Because in the above example, I would get this printed out:

```
select * from whatever where key = thing
```

which is missing the quoting. I want to know what the **actual sql** would be so I can cut and paste it into a sql editor and run the query myself while debugging. ("actual SQL" basically means "what the equivalent sql would be" and can probably be found by asking the cursor to preform the bindings and return the string. but how?)

Comment: `execute` executes what you tell it to execute. In this case, you created a query string through string formatting which exposes you to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead. **NO** amount of quoting can avoid the injection and conversion errors caused by string concatenations.

Comment: I think the answer may depend on which database you are using. For example, with postgres, you can use [`mogrify`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify).

Comment: This might not be quite that straightforward since with prepared statements and placeholders there may not exist a concrete SQL statement with the constant values "quoted in" at any point in time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Read the question again... OP is using parameterized queries, and that's part of their issue.

Comment: @Alasdair the answer is the same for all databases. Don't quote, use parameterized/server-bound queries

Comment: I'd really love a pure db-api answer. I'd accept an answer for each of oracle, sqlite3 (and ideally postgresql)

Comment: @AKX in which case, what's the question?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "When using parametrized queries, is there a way to get a concrete query I could e.g. paste into an external SQL editor?".

Comment: @drysdam I suspect you misunderstand how parameterized queries work. The query isn't modified at all. It's sent to the server as is, including the parameter names. The *binary values* are sen't separately in the same RPC call. The server will use them *as parameters* to execute a parameterized query

Comment: @AKX in that case the answer is again `whatever you provided`

Comment: It doesn't matter how parameterized queries work. The question is how can I get the equivalent SQL for debugging purposes.

Comment: @drysdam *you already have it*. It's whatever is in `sql`. The parameter *values* are *not* part of the query. Are you trying to ask something different perhaps? How to log the values?

Comment: If I paste 'select * from whatever where key = :key' into a SQL editor, I will get an error. I want the sql that returns the same results as the parameterized query.\

Comment: @drysdam if you want to log the entire RPC call the easiest choice would be to do so at the server, using the database's tracing/profiling mechanisms.

Comment: I don't want to log the entire RPC call. Maybe you should read the question again.

Comment: @drysdam does the error say that you forgot to define that parameter? Then define that parameter and give it a value. That's the whole point of parameterized queries. The *values* are *not* part of the query. Why don't you modify *your* code to log the values, not just the query? Or why not use the database's tracing to log the entire RPC call?

Comment: @drysdam maybe I'm using databases for 20 years and use traces and logs for performance tuning all the time. Your assumptions are simply wrong. *Even at the driver level* the query and values are separate. On the wire, they are separate. On the server, they are separate

Comment: You may be able to configure dbapi or the ODBC driver to log the call, including the parameters. There's no other "actual sql"